# How to create database on different host from schema-first model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I have a pre-existing database and Entity Framework 6 *database-first* model generated from it. I need to create the same database on a different host and/or database engine. I hoped I could use the same model as *code-first*, but `OnModelCreating` method of the generated `DbContext` seems to be protected from being used for code-first approach, it throws `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`. Generated models don't have any attributes applied too.

Is there any way to reuse my database-first model to create a database with the same schema? Or maybe there's an obvious and much simpler way to do it that I'm missing?

Comment: If you want to create the database why do you need to touch the OnModelCreating? You should be able to do this from the designer (right click on the designer surface and select "Generate Database From Model" and run the script) or if you want to do this from code do `ctx.Database.Create()` or use the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer.

Comment: @Pawel Oh. I guess that's "an obvious and much simpler way" I expected to exist. :) Thanks for pointing in the right direction. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to create the database you shouldn't need to touch the `OnModelCreating` method. You should be able to do this from the designer (right click on the designer surface and select "Generate Database From Model" and run the script) or if you want to do this from code do `ctx.Database.Create()` or use the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer.